# Many to many nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

```
public class Movie
{
public int id;
public string Title;
public IList<Director> dirs;
}

public class Director
{
public string Name;
public DateTime birthday;
}
```

Is this possible to map to a schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `movie` (
  `m_ID` varchar(9) NOT NULL 
  `Title` varchar(255) NOT NULL 
  PRIMARY KEY (`m_ID`),
  KEY `m_ID` (`ReleaseDate`,`Title`,)
)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `m_director` (
  `dirID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dirName` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `birthday` date 
  PRIMARY KEY (`dirID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `dirName` (`dirName`)
) 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `m_directs` (
  `m_ID` char(9) NOT NULL
  `dirID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `m_ID_2` (`m_ID`,`dirID`),
  KEY `m_ID` (`m_ID`),
  KEY `dirID` (`dirID`)
)
```

without maintaining a IList of Movie inside class Director? I guess what I really want is just a way to ensure no duplicate director names in the m_director table, allow for multiple directors of a movie and not have the Director class care what movies they direct.

Would it be better to just add a list of movies a Director has directed? How do I stop the same movie from being added here twice?

Comment: The question is confusing. Whether you choose to maintain a list of movies a director has directed is up to you to decide, depending on whether you need that information in your program. And it has no bearing on how you ensure that there are no duplicate names in the m_director table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are talking about is an important part of your business logic. It should manage the directors, ensure that they aren't duplicated and ensure that movies aren't added twice. It doesn't have anything to do with NHibernate. It's just plain old application programming.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so it's possible to map your scenario without using an IList of Movies in your Director class... Because this in many to many mapping this is how relationship is defined on both sides...

Comment: I don't understand why you are saying this. You can map any many-to-many relation from a one side and not from the other.

Comment: @Stefan--can you give an example how to do this?

Comment: @user623879: take any example of a many-to-many relation which is not bidirectional. E.g. http://ayende.com/blog/4043/nhibernate-mapping-list